# Windirstat that takes into account symlinks

Tags: windows, gratis, file-management

I happen to have quite a few symlinks floating around on my SSD that link to large files on another drive (`.ost,.pst,.msi` etc).

WinDirStat seems to count these files as being on the SSD, when in fact they are not.

Is there a tool that is:

1. Free (beer)
2. Does at least the core of what WinDirStat does? (Gives a graphical overview of where space is being taken up)
3. Runs on Windows (8)

Are there programs that meet these criteria?

Comment: I used to use Spacemonger for a while but I noticed that it too, gets tripped-up by Windows 10's filesystem trickery - but I don't know if Windows 10 is using symlinks or hard-links or reparse points or junction points or something else. Then there's also the new stuff they added for OneDrive and "reserved files". Hmmm.